# How to only affect siblings with Last of type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to target the last div in a container but my styles only seem to affect the child divs and not the sibling divs. How do I constrain those styles to the sibling level?

In the code below, the last .sibling should be affected but every .child-2 is getting affected. I've also tried adding > for a direct descendent but it did not work.

```css
.my-container div:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">

  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="child-1">
      Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      Child 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="child-1">
      Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      Child 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="child-1">
      Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      Child 2
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So child 1 and child 2 in the last div should be red?

Comment: the selector should be `.my-container div.sibling:last-of-type{...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your selector should be 
`.my-container div.sibling:last-of-type{...}`

```css
.my-container div.sibling:last-of-type {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">

  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="child-1">
      Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      Child 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="child-1">
      Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      Child 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="child-1">
      Child 1
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      Child 2
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but last-of-type does not affect class names. That's what's causing all my problems.

Comment: @ClintonGreen I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve then... which elements should be targeted? the last `sibling` (and all children)? or which ones?

Comment: see updated, only targets sibling (it does not add border to children) - which browser are you using? (Chrome here)

Comment: Hi thanks that works great. Im not sure why it's not working on my side.

Answer (score 2):

```
.my-container div.sibling:last-of-type {
  color: red;
}
/* will be the code */
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but last-of-type does not affect class names. Life would be much easier if it did.

Comment: its working if you are targeting the last sibling only not its child...

Comment: Sorry it must be something else in my project preventing it from working. Cheers

Comment: i guess its your browser

Comment: No offense but why would he do that when he already said your answer didn't help?

Comment: No offence but can't you see he has ticked the above answer.. and mine answer is same too.